# sass gets compiled but does not run in my browser

Tags: html, css, sass

this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>nested</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.scss">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "class1">
         <h1>Heading</h1>
         <p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
         <p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
         <div class = "class2">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
         </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my style.scss:

```
.class1{
   h1{
      font-size: 25px;
      color:#E45456;
   }

   #p1{
      font-size: 25px;
      color:#3C7949;
   }
   #p2{
      font-size: 25px;
      color:#3C7949;
   }

   .class2{
      h1{
         font-size: 25px;
         color:#E45456;
      }

      p{
         font-size: 45px;
         color:#3C7949;
      }
   }
}
```

My style.scss gets compiled in the command prompt and a new style.css is also generated. But on web browser my page does not have any of the styles which I gave to it.

Comment: do you not have to add the `style.css` not `style.scss`?

Comment: It's because you're referencing a Sass file and not a CSS file. You should change your stylesheet link to `style.css`

Comment: thanks. That was a blunder from my side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, you need to give reference of your `CSS` file not the `SCSS` file.
The browser cannot render a `SCSS` file for styling.

Check your html code, you referenced wrong file.
[image]

Comment: @pratteekshaurya welcome. You can mark my answer as correct and close this question.